# Dismiss ViewController + Table ViewController + Master-Detail app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a Master-Detail application. Both master and detail are UITableViewControllers. In detail scene I created a button and call to it action

```
- (IBAction)completeTaskButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [[self delegate] removeCompletedTask:self.indexFromRow controller:self];
}
```

In Master VC implementation I have method

```
- (void) removeCompletedTask:(NSInteger)index controller:(DetailViewController *) controller {
    [self.dataController.masterTasksList removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

These method must delete selected row and go back to the Master View. The problem is that it removes the row but DONT dismiss detail view. Any help will be usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your master-detail setup involves a navigation controller. If you want to dismiss the detail view in the same manner as would tapping the Back button, use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.

Answer (score 1):

try
                   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
or you could try:

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES].
```

You are popping the view controller which is the opposite of pushViewController:

Comment: I have tried to change storyboard segue from Push to Modal and it works, but I need to use Push